# How can I sample from a table with weights

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
view   weight
A      1
B      1
C      2
D      1
E      1
F      1
G      3
```

I would like to sample from this table, but use the `weight` column to determine the probability of being chosen. For the above table, A, B, D, E, and F would all be chosen with probability 0.1, C would be with probability 0.2 and G would be probability 0.3

Answers with python or SQL would be great.

Comment: You mean you want to chose a character `randomly` from the `view` column based on the probability in `weight` column?

Comment: @AliShan Yes, sorry if I wasn't being clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by multiplying each row by its respective weight, and then randomly selecting a single row, so a view assigned a weight of 3 will be represented three times, increasing its likelihood of being selected.:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
  (VALUES ROW(1), ROW(2), ROW(3)) 
) d (weight) on d.weight <= t.weight
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/g4Ng3jAb)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with mysql using something like

```
SELECT view, -LOG(RAND()) / weight AS priority FROM your_table ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1
```

Although I haven't tested it. I'd always prefer to to it in python, as I find it much more readable and extendable. In python, you can use numpy's [random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

I got the following code to work

```
import numpy as np

views = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
weights = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]

weights = np.array(weights) / np.sum(weights)

sampled_view = np.random.choice(views, size=1, p=weights, replace=False)[0]


print(f"Sampled view: {sampled_view}")
```